# How to call child component method from parent component method only after subscribing httpClient observables?

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rxjs

If ya'll wouldn't mind helping me...

Originally I tried to have to 2 completely different files send to 2 completely different s3 buckets (filesArray1 to s3 bucket 1 and filesArray2 to s3 bucket 2) using 1 subscribe(), but the problem I've been facing was that the observable to send filesArray1 gets somehow rewritten to send filesArray2 to both s3 bucket 1 and s3 bucket 2 instead.

I know that some of you might think I can just 2 different subscriptions, but more my use-case, they needed to be in 1 subscription because file2 contains the response after the observable to send file1 is done..
It kinda looked like this in the end...

```
this.httpClient.post(apiEndpoint, filesArray1)     // retrieve S3 presign urls for each file
  .pipe(
  mergeMap( ResponseWithS3Urls => {

    const firstPostObservables = ResponseWithS3Urls.map((urls, index) => {

      return this.httpClient.post(urls, filesArray1[index]);    // Send files to S3 bucket 1
    }

    return forkJoin([forkJoin(firstPostObservables), of(ResponseWithS3Urls)]);  // Return post observables and the response from the 1st observable
  },
  mergeMap(res => {
    /* 
       Generate new JSON files (filesArray2) containing the location where each file was sent to. Do HTTP POST to get different URLS for 
       filesArray2.
       Then HTTP POST filesArray2 to those URLS.
       return 1st and 2nd set of observables to subscribe.
    */
  })
)
.subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
}
```

Anyway, I think I gave up on that method anyways because I'm thinking now (I'm new to rxjs so this is new to me) that one can only subscribe observables containing ONE set of files ... so then I started thinking of trying to make a child component to send filesArray2 to s3 bucket 2 and then call that child component in the subscription.. but I'm getting

```
Cannot read property 'childComponentFunction' of undefined
  at SafeSubscriber._next (parentComponent.ts)
  at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js)
  at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js)
  at SafeSubscriber._next (Subscriber.js)
  at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js)
  at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js)
  at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js)
  at InnerSubscriber.next (InnerSubscriber.js)
  at Object.complete (forkJoin.js)
  at Object.wrappedComplete (Subscriber.js)
```

All I did was add

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent)
private childComponent: ChildComponent
```

Then in the

```
.subscribe(res => { })
 contained...
  this.childComponent.childComponentFunction(res);     // Do 2nd set of observables here instead
```

Do you guys have any thoughts on this by any chance?

Comment: If you queried the child comp that way,  make sure you call `childComponent.func()` in the `ngAfterViewInit` hook.

Comment: Yeah I figured that was the case, but I wasn't sure since I'm not too familiar with Angular yet. Thank you for validating that for me though :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to attach reference to a child template and using that reference you can use all the child methods. Let's take an example here.

```
@Component({

template : <app-child #childAccess> </app-child>

})
export class ParentComponent {
@ViewChild('childAccess', { static: false }) childComponent : ChildComponent;
childComponent.childMethod(); 
}

@Component({
selector : 'app-child'
styles :[]
template : <h1>Hello Child</h1>

})
export class ChildComponent {

  childMethod(){
  console.log('Child method works');
   }

}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much for this.... I seriously thought there was no way to do what I needed to do....

But do you mind answering me this one question? Is it really not possible to 1 observable sending 1 set of files to a location and another different observable to send another different set of files to a different location in a single subscribe?? 

I never thought this would've happened, because I figured that the httpClient observable is only made is relative to the file you are sending via POST/PUT